# pd.datetime on a dataframe with one row fails

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe df with one row and following columns

```
NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE
XYZ   01/01/2023
```

With the below statement when I convert the columns START_DATE and END_DATE to date column

```
df.loc[:, 'START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'])
df.loc[:, 'END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE'])
```

I get the error 'Cannot convert float to NaN'

But the wierd thing is that if the dataframe df has more than one row

```
NAME, START_DATE,  END_DATE
Nick  01/01/2023          
Jack  01/05/2023
```

the statement works fine.

So why does it fail when there is only one row in the dataframe?

I tried many options but in vain.  Any suggestions would be great help

Comment: Why do you use `df.loc[:, 'START_DATE']`? Do: `df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.loc[:, 'START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'])` tries to keep the original dtype, which might be the reason for your error.

You should replace the whole column:

```
df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'], errors='coerce')
```